# Finding the Object Property with the highest value in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Say I had an object created dynamically like so...

```
var indexes = {};
for (var i = 0; i < specchar.length; i++) {
    indexes[specchar[i]] = str.indexOf(specchar[i]);
}
```

How would I find the property with the highest value?

Comment: Please add the variable `specchar`. or rather post the part which deals with finding the highest value

Comment: It shouldn't necessarily matter, but it's an array... `var specchar = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];`

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of the max value. If you encounter a value that is larger, update the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is to keep track of the max value as your object is being dynamically created like so:

```
var indexes = {};
var maxVal = str.indexOf(specchar[0]); // contains largest value
var maxKey = ''; // contains key corresponding to largest value
for (var i = 0; i < specchar.length; i++) {
  var val = str.indexOf(specchar[i]);
  if (val > maxVal) {
    maxVal = val;
    maxKey = specchar[i];
  }
  indexes[specchar[i]] = val;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` can return -1. So using 0 as initial value for `maxVal` is questionable. Also you seem to have forgotten to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You also can find max value using `Math.max.apply`. If you work with object then first need get values and push into array.

```
var fixtures = {};
for (var i = 0; i < Math.random() * 20 + 5; i++) {
    fixtures[i] = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
}

// Procceed object and push values to array
var values = [],
    maxValue = 0;
for (var key in fixtures) {
    values.push(fixtures[key]);
}

// Find max value
maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math.max, values);

// Print results to console
console.dir(values);
console.log(maxValue);
```

But if you get an array `values` and you want find max value from, you can just call `Math.max.apply(Math.max, values)` an it returns max value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `for-in`.

```
var indexes = {};
var maxIndexVal = str.indexOf(specchar[0]); // this will hold the maximum value found

for(var index in specchar){

   var foundIndex = str.indexOf(specchar[index]); // returns the index if found

   // compare values; add max values to indexes
   if(foundIndex > maxIndexVal) {
        maxIndexVal = foundIndex;
        indexes[specchar[maxIndexVal]] = maxIndexVal;
   }

}
```